# Extract and reformat PostgreSQL query output (python)

Tags: python-3.x, postgresql

I'm querying a PostgreSQL database with asyncpg.  My query is checking a table to determine if a specific record number exist.  If the record exist then the date_modified information is extracted from that record, which I need to compare with a newly collected date.

My current issue is trying to extract the timestamp information from the list, which is returned by the query, which is shown below:

```
[<Record date_modified=datetime.datetime(2010, 9, 9, 8, 33, 31)>]
```

The only way that I have found to obtain the date string is with a regex.

```
 date_modified = re.search(r'(\d{4},\s\d{1,2},\s\d{1,2},\s\d{1,2},\s\d{1,2},\s\d{1,2})',  repr(date_check))

 print (date_modified.group(0))

 outputs: 2010, 9, 9, 8, 33, 31
```

How do I convert the output above to this format?

```
2010-09-09 08:33:31
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem by doing this:

```
date_modified = re.search(r'(\d{4},\s\d{1,2},\s\d{1,2},\s\d{1,2},\s\d{1,2},\s\d{1,2})',  repr(date_check))
reformattedDate = datetime.datetime.strptime(date_modified.group(0), '%Y, %m, %d, %H, %M, %S').strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
```

Comment: Is `date_check` already a `datetime.datetime`?  If so, you don't need the `re`, just `reformattedDate = date_check.strptime('%Y ...')` as Mayank suggested.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
import datetime

In [1465]: datetime.datetime.strftime(date_modified,'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
Out[1465]: '2010-09-09 08:33:31'
```

Read the doc [strftime](http://strftime.org/) for more info.

Comment: My primary issue is extracting the date_modified information from the returned query.

Comment: Does the list has just one element? or more? If it has more, can you please share some? That'll give me a better idea.

Comment: The list only has the one element as shown in my original post.

Comment: I know that I can do this: re.search(r'(\d{4},\s\d{1,2},\s\d{1,2},\s\d{1,2},\s\d{1,2},\s\d{1,2})',  repr(test)), but I was wondering if there is another way.

Comment: I was also trying at my end. Looks like too much parsing is required for it.